# rounding float to an integer

Tags: python

Hello intelligent programmers:

I have a question about rounding to the nearest 1 in python.

Below is my output:

```
 ============Birth Month Distribution============
            Number  Percent

 January    2       7.41
 February   2       7.41
 March      2       7.41
 April      2       7.41
 May        2       7.41
 June       2       7.41
 July       2       7.41
 August     2       7.41
 September  2       7.41
 October    2       7.41
 November   3       11.11
 December   4       14.81


==================== Histogram ====================

    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
02  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
03  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
04  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
05  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
06  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
07  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
08  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
09  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
10  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
11  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
12  |  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  ** 
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

input:

```
 january=months.count(1)
 januaryPercent=float(round(((january/counter)*100),2))
 januaryNumber=int((((january/counter)*100)//1))
 januaryHistogram=januaryNumber*" ** "
```

For example:
December has four numbers in it, which makes the percent 14.81. What I need is to multiply " ** " by 15 rather than 14. I am not sure how to round up... If anyone could give me some pointers. That would be much appreciated. The code above is used for every month to gather my "histogram".

Comment: Are you using 12 variables to store those numbers? If so, you should first figure out how to store them as a list with 12 items.

Comment: @gnibbler: Actually wouldn't it be more like 4 * 12 == 48 variables?

Comment: @martineau, hard to tell. I can only assume there are at least 12 variables names jan-dec. Perhaps there is a loop around those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *round* using `round`:

```
>>> december="14.81"
>>> round(float(december))
 15.0
```

If you want it to be an *int*, then use `int`.

```
>>> december="14.81"
>>> int(round(float(december)))
15
```

Fairly straightforward.

### EDIT (as per the OP's comments to this answer):

Soooo... you're gonna have `decemberNumber` being `14.81` (or whatever... It doesn't matter: that's what variables are for)... and you want to show 15 (the closest `int`, rather) chunks of `" ** "` characters. If that's the case, the code below should work:

```
decemberHistogram=int(round(float(decemberNumber)))*" ** "
```

Comment: I have no idea that it will be "14.81" though is the problem.

Comment: December could equal any sort of percentage, so I can't set December to a specific number.

Comment: You don't set it... Your put it into your variable and let `float`, `round` and everything do their stuff. I've edited again, anyway. If this is not it, then there's something I'm definitely missing...

Comment: Sir, sir... Btw, if this answered your question, you should consider selecting it as the "selected answer" (the green tick to the left of the answer). It'll help people who find this question in the future, it'll give you rep., it'll give me rep., it'll encourage other people answer your questions in the future (OPs who systematically don't choose answers are not very well... _perceived_ ) Win Win!!